# How to use Clebsch-Gordan coefficient in this situation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

The background of this problem is a 1$\to$2 decay process, where the initial particle has spin 1/2 and $s_z=1/2$, one of the final state particles is a scalar particle and has spin 0, the other has spin 1/2. I want to discuss the $s_z$ of that final state particle.

Here's my analysis, according to angular momentum conservation law, we have

[image]

and

[image]

where $l$ is the relative orbital angular momentum between two final particles, essentially I can write

[image]

If there are only the last two terms, then I can use the C-G coefficient directly, but now I don't know how to determine a,b and c at the same time.

Should I just naively take $a=1/\sqrt{2}$ and adjust the value of b and c accordingly?

Comment: Why are you including $|1,1\rangle$ and $|1,0\rangle$ for the scalar particle? I would think that $b=c=0$ and $a=1$ just from the fact that the scalar particle has no spin, but maybe I don't understand the situation.

Comment: although scalar particle has no spin, they could have orbital angular momentum as well, leading their total angular momentum being 1.